# Is there any database of Autonomous Systems (AS) and IP address spaces an AS is allocated?

Tags: networking, bgp

as IP address spaces are allocated to different ASes, there must be an API or database somewhere where I can find all addresses an AS can originate ?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/q/137257/87017 and http://superuser.com/q/707902/78897

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is such a database. You can find it on the RIPE web site. There is also an API to query the database with your custom application:

https://labs.ripe.net/ripe-database/database-api/api-introduction

or if you just need to search from the web page you can use the search button at this page:

http://www.ripe.net/data-tools/db

Comment: Isn't this just one of the five RIRS?